# Copying custom function to other cells (changing active cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make this custom function work when I copy in a number of cells. The function should fill in the cells between two numbers with a lineer increase.

```
Function HINT(FirstCell, LastCell)

x = FirstCell.Column
y = LastCell.Column
a = FirstCell
b = LastCell
step = (b - a) / Abs(x - y)
Actcellc = ActiveCell.Column
HINT = FirstCell + (Actcellc - x) * step
End Function
```

It works if I copy it to each cell between firstcell and lastcell one by one but doesn't work if I just select the range inbetween and copy (Just calculates the same number in each cell because it still sees the active cell as the origin of copy. If I copy one by one the active cell changes and function works correctly). I can understand that I need to change the activecell definition to another thing but I just don't know what.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I will answer my own question with the helps of others:

```
Function HINT(FirstCell, LastCell, pos As Range)

Dim i As Long
Dim res() As Double
Dim rng As Range

x = FirstCell.Column
y = LastCell.Column
a = FirstCell
b = LastCell
step = (b - a) / Abs(x - y)

HINT = FirstCell + (pos.Column - x) * step

End Function
```

In the first blank cell (in this case C2) the code should be entered like this:
=hint($B$2,$N$2,C2)

$B$2 First value, fixed / 
$N$2 Last value, fixed  / 
C2 for position, first blank cell to be filled.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an array function instead:

```
Function HINT2(FirstCell, LastCell)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim res() As Double

    x = FirstCell.Column
    y = LastCell.Column
    a = FirstCell
    b = LastCell
    step = (b - a) / Abs(x - y)

    ReDim res(1 To (y - x - 1)) As Double

    For i = 1 To y - x - 1
        res(i) = FirstCell + i * step   
    Next

    HINT2 = res


End Function
```

To use it, select all the cells between the two bounds, enter the function name and arguments into the formula bar, and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Alternatively, you may choose to supply a 'position' parameter, which would return a single value and allow to easily copy to multiple cells:

```
Function HINT3(FirstCell, LastCell, pos As Long)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim res() As Double

    x = FirstCell.Column
    y = LastCell.Column
    a = FirstCell
    b = LastCell
    step = (b - a) / Abs(x - y)

    HINT3 = FirstCell + pos * step

End Function
```

You would probably want to have the 'position' numbers 1..n in a row above this formula - similar to this:

[image]

Also, declaring variables is strongly recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like magic. Still I wonder how come functions like vlookup works when you just copy them in a range?

Comment: VLOOKUP does not depend in its own location to get the answer. Instead, you pass a number corresponding to the column you want. I would be happy to post a modified version of the above function that works this way, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, please. I would be very happy.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration. I thought more about VLOOKUP and added a pos as range. I believe I was genius :) See my edit which works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fill in multiple cells.  You need either a function that returns an array or a **Sub**

Here is the sub approach.  Say we want to fill in the cells between **A1** and **M1**

[image: before]

This small macro:

```
Sub FillMissingInRow()
    Dim r As Range, v1 As Double, v2 As Double, inc As Double
    Set r = Range("A1:M1")
    v1 = r(1)
    v2 = r(r.Count)
    inc = (v2 - v1) / (r.Count - 1)
    r.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=inc, Trend:=False
End Sub
```

will result in:

[image: after]

Comment: Thanks but I need to make it a function to use it rapidly without changing codes. I will distrubute the function to my team and I am the only one that can write codes. Could you explain the array option also?

Comment: I have tested **AFischbein's** answer to your question and it works just fine!  Use that method.